# Peskin & Schroeder's QFT on page 200

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, scattering-cross-section

On Peskin & Schroeder's QFT book page 200, in the second paragraph, the book said: "$\cdots$ by making the replacement $e\rightarrow e\cdot F_{1}(q^2) $. The cross section for the process $\bf{p}\rightarrow\bf{p^{\prime}}$ is therefore"
$$
\frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega} \simeq\left(\frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega}\right)_{0} \cdot\left[1-\frac{\alpha}{\pi} f_{\mathrm{IR}}\left(q^{2}\right) \log \left(\frac{-q^{2} \text { or } m^{2}}{\mu^{2}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\alpha^{2}\right)\right] \ \ \ \ \ (6.63)
$$
which is related with $F_{1}\left(q^{2}\right)$
$$
F_{1}\left(q^{2}\right)=1-\frac{\alpha}{2 \pi} f_{\mathrm{IR}}\left(q^{2}\right) \log \left(\frac{-q^{2} \text { or } m^{2}}{\mu^{2}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\alpha^{2}\right)
$$
However, I thought the eq.$(6.63)$ should be
$$
\frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega} \simeq\left(\frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega}\right)_{0} \cdot\left[1-\frac{\alpha}{\pi} f_{\mathrm{IR}}\left(q^{2}\right) \log \left(\frac{-q^{2} \text { or } m^{2}}{\mu^{2}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\alpha^{2}\right)\right]^2
$$
Since for cross section, it's up to $|M|^2$, where $M$ is the amplitude of the Feynman diagram. Here we already have $M\sim F_1(q^2)$, so for cross-section should be $~ [F_1(q^2)]^2$.

By the way, is here a typo in $(6.63)$ about $\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$, which might be $\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$?

If you have any comment or answer, I am really appreciate it.

Comment: He's using $(1 + x)^2 \approx 1 + 2x$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you very much!